# Casting by a variable of class

Tags: ruby, casting

I can cast a string to float via:

```
Float("1")
```

Now I have this:

```
f = Float
```

How can I use `f` to cast a string to float?

**Edited**

I'm sorry for not being clear.

Here is my scenario:

I'm using [Redis DB](http://redis.io), via gem [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb). Basically `redis-db` stores values as strings. When I map back values from DB to my objects, I wish to cast them to some primitive types for easy to use.

So I use this:

```
require 'ostruct'

class Person < OpenStruct

    MAP = { :name => String, :age => Fixnum }

    ##
    # This reads data from DB, and converts them to some "primitive" types
    # for easy use.
    #
    def read
        MAP.each_pair do |sym, cls|
            # read data as string from DB, via key `sym.to_s`
            s = ...
            # now I have `cls`, how can I "cast" `s` to `cls`?
            self[sym] = ???

            # I know I can "iterate" all types by this:
            #
            # if cls.is_a? Float
            #     self[sym] = s.to_f
            # elsif cls.is_a? Fixnum
            #     self[sym] = s.to_i
            # ...
            #
            # But in Python I can just cast `s` to `cls` in one line...
            # So I wonder if there is some way to cast `s` to `cls` in Ruby?
        end
    end # read

end # Person
```

Saying "for easy use", I mean I want to:

```
p = Person.new
p.read
# I want to access `age` as an integer, not a string
if p.age +-*/ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `f` to do it. The `Float` in `Float("1")` is a method. The `Float` in `f = Float` is a class (an object). They are different things.

Comment: Thank you, I checked all method names of `f` but couldn't find a hint. In Python I can do this `type(1.0)("1")`. Could you point me to some methods which are somehow possible to achieve that?

Comment: @Ybur you should do `(1.0).to_i.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from your question you want this:

```
result = '1'.to_f  #outputs => 1.0
```

then for string:

```
result.to_s  #outputs => "1.0"
```

And you can also do it in one step as well:

```
'1'.to_f.to_s #outputs => "1.0"
```

For more about strings and ruby you can see [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html)